# Codenameone - App Crash on Android Tablet and opens a blank black screen from next time

Tags: android, codenameone

App Crash on Android Tablet and when ever tried to open it again it open a blank black screen there after. This is happening with android debug build.I have tried to replicate the issue on simulator and it didn't happen. Please let me know if any clues about this issue. Is it something related to inefficient memory usage or something else. Is there any tool I can use to narrow down this issue. This is not happening on IOS devices and even Android Phones.

[image]

Comment: You need to connect the device with a cable and use the device monitor tool from Android Studio or logcat. This used to be a standalone tool but now you need to launch the entire Android Studio and then go to the device monitor (which is still a separate tool to see this).  Notice that if you have a pro account crash protection might help: https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---use-crash-protection-get-device-logs.html

Comment: To get the native log (logcat) without the need of Android Studio and without connect the device to a computer, you can also use the "Native Logs Reader" CN1lib, available in the Codename One extensions. If you have a Pro account, you can send to your email (by `Log.sendLog`) the standard log and the native log (if you attached it to the standard log).

Comment: Thank You Shai and Francesco. This is happening in one of the testing device which I don't have access to. IT was not occurring on my device. How can I debug this issue  remotely. Log.sendLog() pro feature only works when the App go to production correct? Does this work for debug test build also? Please advise.

Comment: You can use the standard `Log.sendLog()` and the "Native Logs Reader" CN1Lib in every app, also with a debug build. However, in my experience, the devices in a device farm can have strange behaviors that don't occur in my devices, so the problem can be caused by the device farm itself rather than by the app.

Comment: @FrancescoGalgani - How can we debug the issues with device farm. I'm pretty new to this. Can you give me some information. Also, Native Logs Reader can be included in Main class and Log.sendLog should send the email with log when ever error occurs.right?

Comment: About your second question, I replied here: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/native-logging-certificate-wizard.html#comment-3952696116